Why use await and wait_for() in the same line in Playwright?
I am following an online tutorial for scraping with Playwright (https://jsoma.github.io/advanced-scraping-with-playwright/). There is one line that uses both await and wait_for(), and I don't understand why. Isn't that redundant? Why not just use one or the other?
township_numbers = ['129', '130', '135']

for num in township_numbers:
    print("Searching for page", num)
    await page.locator("#ddmTownship").select_option(num)
    await page.get_by_text("Submit", exact=True).click()

    # Wait for the table to show up - this is the line that confuses me
    await page.get_by_text('CTB No').wait_for()

    html = await page.content()
    tables = pd.read_html(html)
    df = tables[2]

    filename = f"{num}.csv"
    print("Got it - saving as", filename)
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)


await is a general keyword. It doesn't wait for an element, it waits for an async coroutine to resolve.
The confusion is probably the fact that await sounds like you're "awaiting" for an element to appear on the screen, but it's unrelated to waiting, Playwright, HTML and browser automation per se.
locator.wait_for() is a Playwright-specific action that waits for an element queried by a locator to appear. In Playwright's sync API, there's no need to add await in front of it because there's no coroutine. You'd just call it like normal Python code, and it still waits for the element.
Since you're using the async API, though, basically all Playwright calls will use await to preserve sequential ordering of the coroutines from top to bottom. In some cases, you'll want to run things in parallel or out of order, but for starters you'll mostly write top-to-bottom sequentially chained coroutines like the program you've shared here.
So, to summarize:

await: wait for a coroutine to complete before moving on to the next line of code. Nothing specific to Playwright or browser automation.
locator.wait_for(): wait for an element to appear on the screen, and return either an await-able coroutine, or return synchronously once the element appears, depending on the async or sync Playwright API you're using.

As an exercise, try rewriting the code from the tutorial using the sync API, which is easier to work with at first (if a bit less powerful for advanced use cases). This should make the distinction between the async Python API and the Playwright API clear.
